# Adding and editing comments on the same page

Tags: django-forms, django-views

In my app, I have a view showing an article and the list of related comments. An authorized user can leave a comment or several comments, and I've already realized this functionality. Where I got stuck is how to make it possible for a user to edit or delete their comments. The tricky point is all these actions (add, edit, delete) should be performed *on the same page*. What is the best approach for achieving this?

The model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    comments = models.ForeignKey(NewsItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='comments')
    text = models.TextField(blank = False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

The form:

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['text',]
```

The view:

```
<...>

    if request.method == 'POST':        
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.comments = NewsItem(id = newsitem_id)
            new_comment.author = User(id = request.user.id)
            new_comment.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('news:newsitem_slug', args=(newsitem_id, slug)) + '#comment_{0}'.format(new_comment.id))
    else:
        form = CommentForm()

<...>
```

The template:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
       <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Leave a comment">
   </form>
{% endif %}
```

And this is the list of comments, where the form for editing should be placed:

```
<ul>
      {% for comment in newsitem.get_active_comments %}
          <li>{{ comment.text }}<br>
           {{ comment.author }} </li>
           {% if comment.author == user %}
              The form for editing and the button for deleting should be here.
           {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The page is supposed to look like this:

```
Caption

Text text text text text text
text text text text text text.

Comments:

    Comment 1 by an authorised user
    Edit | Delete

    Comment 2

    Comment 3 by an authorised user
    Edit | Delete

    Comment 4

    Comment 5

    Write a comment [Form]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should manage this using ajax calls.
This is the most 'easy' way to manage this and stay in the same page.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion, but I'm more concerned about managing multiple forms on the same page (one for adding and several for editing). Reload of the page isn't problematic, so I don't think AJAX is needed.

Comment: So basicaly you need to triger post request using javascript to each a tag (or button) and pass it the id of the comment you need to edit/delete you can also pass.
You can create a separate view to handle edit or delete of the comment.
If you need to know wich page you need to redirect at the end you can pass an hidden field trough the form with the id on the page you need.